# Array not initialized in the backend

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, ionic-framework

I am trying to send a user object upon registration. This user object has many properties which are sent to the backend and added to the database correctly. However, there is one property, an array called `vouchers`, which when I add, the user object is not sent to the database.

Here is the code for the user object being sent to the backend from the ionic frontend:

```
   let userobj = {
            username: this.username,
            name: this.name,
            region: this.region,
            building: this.building,
            password: this.password,
            confirmPassword: this.confirmpassword,
            points: 300,
            vouchers: [{ companyId: "", companyname: "" }]
          };
```

In the backend, this is the mongoose model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Voucher = mongoose.Schema.Types.Voucher;

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  region: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  building: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 0
  },
  points: {
    type: Number,
    required: false,
    min: 0
  },
  vouchers: {
    type: [Object],
    status: [String],
    required: false,
    default: []
  },

  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updatedAt: Date
});

mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

define `vouchers` has an array of objects

```
vouchers: [{
    type: [Object], // There is no Schema Type in moongoose, change to [String]
    status: [String]
}]
```

donno about your `vouchers: [{ companyId: "", companyname: "" }]`

you want to use `companyId` and `companyname`

Change the schema..

`vouchers: [{ companyId: String, companyname: String }]`